# Array search and filter in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, frontend

I am trying to make  displaying icons based on user search

example **"computer"** is the actual icon name and **["laptop", "tablet", "device" ]** these are tags of computer icon name

We will have to display correspond / matching icons based on search with these tags name

```
icons = [{
         "computer" : ["laptop", "tablet", "device" ],
          "mobile" : ["laptop", "tablet", "device" ] ,
          "arrow" : ["left-arrow",  "right-arrow" ] ,
          "left-arrow" : ["arrow",  "right-arrow" ] ,
          "right-arrow" : ["arrow",  "left-arrow" ] ,
          "car" : [ "maruti", "hundai", "road" ],
          "bus" : [ "road" ]
        }]
   const [usersearch, setUsersearch] = ("computer");
```

==========

```
<input defaultValue={usersearch} onChange={(e) => setUsersearch(e.target.value)}  />
    icons.map((ico, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} >
                            <IcoComponent icon={usersearch} /> 
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    export default function App() {
  const icons = {
    computer: ["laptop", "tablet", "device"],
    mobile: ["laptop", "tablet", "device"],
    arrow: ["left-arrow", "right-arrow"],
    "left-arrow": ["arrow", "right-arrow"],
    "right-arrow": ["arrow", "left-arrow"],
    car: ["maruti", "hundai", "road"],
    bus: ["road"],
  };
  const [usersearch, setUsersearch] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        defaultValue={usersearch}
        onChange={(e) => setUsersearch(e.target.value)}
      />

      {icons[usersearch] && icons[usersearch].length
        ? icons[usersearch].map((x, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <IcoComponent icon={x} />
            </div>
          ))
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So here u need to restructure the icons structure from array to object so as to search by key. The user keeps on typing if any key matches the icons the following elements in the value arrays are displayed you can use icon